# how to get every possible sum of list cases

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, while-loop

Hello I am just started to learn python .

I want to create every case of the data in a list

```
if [a,b,c,d,e]

[aa, 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'be'] and so on
```

but I can not figure out how to do it.

This is as far as I can go:

```
def number_of_cases(list_data):

    mix_data=[]
    list_data = list(map(str,list_data))
    for data in list_data:
        mix_data.append(data+list_data[0])
        mix_data.append(data+list_data[1])
        mix_data.append(data+list_data[2])
```

I can not go on doing `list[0 1 2 3 4]` because I do not know how long the list is going to be....

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do a flat list comprehension:

```
data = list('abcd')
pairs = [x+y for x in data for y in data]
pairs
# ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd', 'da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd']
```

Btw., in this particular example it is not even necessary to make a list first

```
pairs = [x+y for x in 'abcd' for y in 'abcd']
```

also works.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `itertools.product`? Given two lists, it will create all the pair-wise combinations of an item from one list and an item from the other, as a sequence of tuples. Then you glue each tuple together.

```
from itertools import product
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
pairs = [''.join(x) for x in product(data, data)]
print(pairs)
```

Answer (score 1):

@AlexL's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43296023/6419007) with `product` is the way to go. Here's a modified version of your code with the desired result:

```
mix_data=[]
list_data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list_data = list(map(str,list_data))
for data1 in list_data:
    for data2 in list_data:
        mix_data.append(data1+data2)
print(mix_data)
```

It outputs:

> ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'ca',
>   'cb', 'cc', 'cd', 'ce', 'da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd', 'de', 'ea', 'eb',
>   'ec', 'ed', 'ee']

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools like @Alex L said or you can also use these simple two loops.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
nlist=[]
for x in list1:      
 for y in list1:
  nlist+=[x+y]
print(nlist)
```

Comment: thank you i wasn`t looking for import tools i needed simple form like this

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion was incorrect, as pointed out below. This answer remains correct.

A cute and terse was to do this is with list comprehensions and f-strings (f-strings are in python 3.6 and up only). EG:

```
chars = 'abcde'
pairs = ['{x}{y}' for x in chars for y in chars]
```

If you don't have f-strings an equivalent would be this:

```
chars = 'abcde'
pairs = ([f'%s%s' % (x, y) for x in chars for y in chars])
```

`>>>print(pairs)
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd', 'ce', 'da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd', 'de', 'ea', 'eb', 'ec', 'ed', 'ee']`

Comment: Did you look at the other answers here? If so didn't you wonder why `itertools.product` and `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` should both give the same result? Hint: try running your second suggestion and compare its true output to the one you posted ;-)

Comment: Ah, you're right. We're talking about permutations and not combinations. Hint: saying 'hint:' is very passive aggressive ;)

Comment: Is it? In that case I apologise.